# Why is package hidden by default? And how can I "unhide" it?

Tags: haskell, package, ghc

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10, and I have the `transformers` module installed via the Ubuntu package `libghc6-transformers-dev`.  For some reason, this package is hidden by default:

```
ghc --make -i./src/ src/fastcgi.hs -o myapp.fcgi

src/MyApp/Webapp.hs:6:7:
    Could not find module `Control.Monad.IO.Class':
      It is a member of the hidden package `transformers-0.2.1.0'.
      Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

So, my first question is, "why?".  And my second question is, what is the proper way to "unhide" this module (without needing to explicitly specify the module via command-line)?  And is that a good/bad idea to do?

Note, I am able to get ghc to compile by passing the package name explicitly, like so:

```
ghc --make -package transformers -i./src/ src/fastcgi.hs -o myapp.fcgi
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the ghc-pkg tool from the command line:

```
ghc-pkg expose transformers
```

Why it was hidden by default I don't know.  It may be something to take up with the Ubuntu package maintainers.

Also,

```
ghc-pkg help
```

will tell you a lot more about this program.

Answer (score 0):

When building with Stack, add `transformers` as a dependency to your `package.yml` file:

```
dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- transformers
```

This fixed the problem permanently for me.